# Problems with recognition of version controller

Tags: git

I'm using rietveld Code Review tool for making some tasks, but it works a bit strange. Their file upload.py, that used for uploading fixes and code, sometimes works well and sometimes says: "Could not guess version control system. Are you in a working copy directory?" . And this happens quite often on the same computer with only one system where there is no changes at all. How can I avoid that or what possible causes of this can be? 
I'm using Windows XP, SP 3 and Git.

Comment: It seems you're running it in the wrong directory. You have to be inside the directory of the project.

Comment: @janos Unfortunatelly, problem isn't so clear. I know this and I know how to use it - problem happens often but not always. I tried a lot of obvious stuff, but nothing helped.

Comment: Are you running the script in Git Bash? And, when it doesn't work, if you change within the same Git Bash window and the same directory, if you keep re-running the command, at some point it just magically works?

Comment: @janos No, after some manipulations with git(just push pull stuff) I run smth like this in cmd : python upload.py -i 12343143, where is number is just number of issue on rierveld. It magically worked two days ago and week before, but sometimes happens what i described. And sometimes it's dissappears. I understand that magic doesnt exist but i can't find out what the problem with this.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the python script. Doesn't it give you other errors or warnings? In any case, you have the script, we can't debug it blindly.

Comment: @janos No, no other messages/logs/warnings/error/etc. Yeah, I understand this - here is the link on script and everything about this - but it's an official script, if we can say so - [link](https://code.google.com/p/rietveld/wiki/CodeReviewHelp) - so i think that problem just in my own computer/system/whatever.

Comment: @janos Well, magic happened - it works again and i sent my changes to this codereview tool, but i think it's not last time. Thanks for your attention but question is still open.